# WP7 toolkit: Gestures on ListBox - selected item

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

using hold gesture on listbox. When the hold is fired the original source is a textblock not the listitem. How do I get the selected item from the gesture? sender is a listbox but the selecteditem/index/items contains nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataContext property of the TextBlock will have the item bound to that ListItem.